# How to track ServiceNow Service Portal (AngularJS) page views with Google Analytics?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, servicenow

I'm seeking help in getting Google Analytics working with ServiceNow's Service Portal (cloud based service management platform).. The platform uses AngularJS.  I have the following code which I have in a header that is on every page:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams){        
    ga('send', {  
        hitType: 'pageview',  
        title: $window.document.title,  
        location: $location.absUrl()  
    });
})
```

When I set a breakpoint in my browser's debugger, I can see the breakpoint is hit and the code is being called.
[image]

But, I'm not seeing anything logged in my Google Analytics real-time dashboard when the above code is called:
[image]

I have tried replacing `$locationChangeSuccess`, `$locationChangeStart`, and `$stateChangeSuccess`

I have tried `$location.absUrl()` and `$location.path()`.

I can't seem to get the above to work.  I would prefer **NOT** to have to use a third party script like [angular-google-analytics](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics) or [autotrack](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) if possible.

Comment: Have you tried `$window.ga(...)`?

Comment: I just tried `$window.ga(...)` and I'm not seeing a difference. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally remembered to look at the browser's console logs and saw the error that was causing my issues: `Error: $window is not defined`

I needed to add `$window` variable in the Client Script function declaration:

```
function ($rootScope, $scope, snRecordWatcher, spUtil, $location, $uibModal, cabrillo, $timeout, $window) {
```